# Charts are getting cut when exporting to pdf using html2pdf

Tags: angular, itext7, export-to-pdf, html2pdf, ng2-charts

I'm using a library (ng2-charts) to create charts in my Angular application and then try to export it to a pdf using html2pdf but the charts are getting cut. Any algorithmic solution for this? Eg: using heights to calculate if the chart can fit to the page or else use the next page.

```
<canvas baseChart 
     [data]="chartData" 
     [labels]="chartLabels" 
     [chartType]="'pie'" 
     [colors]="pieChartColors" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

P.S.

I actually couldn't find a proper library to export charts to pdf in angular as most of them was not fitting in some way. So I used the **itext 7 pdfhtml** for .NET in my back-end to which I send my html. The package is quite easy to use.

Comment: the information you have provided is not enough to give you the solution, provide some more information, show us what u have tried and or rather create stackblitz for the same. So that we can helpp u to solve your problem..

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmqbi7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

This is how my charts look like. could you be able to export it to pdf without the charts getting cut?

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with working on your stackblitz, so i created a git repo for your problem check the link below,

[Charts to pdf](https://github.com/PrashanthGowda/charts-to-pdf.git)

https://github.com/PrashanthGowda/charts-to-pdf.git

Answer (score 0):

I actually couldn't find a proper library to export charts to pdf in angular as most of them was not fitting in some way. So I used the itext 7 pdfhtml for .NET in my back-end to which I send my html. The package is quite easy to use.

https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
  public ExtractPDF()  
  {  
    var data = document.getElementById('htmlData');  
    const divHeight = data.clientHeight
    const divWidth = data.clientWidth
    const ratio = divHeight / divWidth;
    html2canvas(data,
      {
        height: window.outerHeight + window.innerHeight,
        width: window.outerWidth + window.innerWidth,
        windowHeight: window.outerHeight + window.innerHeight,
        windowWidth: window.outerWidth + window.innerWidth,
        scrollX: 0,
        scrollY: 0
      }
      ).then(canvas => {  
      var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "mm", "a4"); 
      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      var width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      var height = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
      pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, width, height*ratio); 
      pdf.save('usuariodispositivo.pdf'); 
    });  
  }
```

this parameters and ratio you can full contain data by img.

Bye

Comment: Dont forget install first  html2canvas and jspdf library by npm and import it.